# Integration by parts on a sum of a product of partial derivatives

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-derivative

Let $\Omega$ be a region $\subset \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose that both $u_{\infty}$ and $\varphi$ $\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$.  Then, I want to perform integration by parts on the following:

$\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_{j}}$

Now, if I follow all the steps of integration by parts as taught to me back in the day by my Calc II professor, I would let $\displaystyle u = \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}}$ and $\displaystyle dv = \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x_{j}}$.  Then, I would calculate $\displaystyle du = \frac{\partial u_{\infty}^{2}}{\partial x_{j}^{2}}$ and $v = \varphi$.

Plugging all this into the integration by parts formula, I would obtain

$\displaystyle uv - \int_{\Omega} v\, du = \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}}\varphi - \int_{\Omega}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial u_{\infty}^{2}}{\partial x_{j}^{2}}\varphi$.

This is part of a problem that we did in my analysis class.  In class, however, the $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}}\varphi$ part was missing from our solution.  In other words, we got that $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_{j}} =  - \int_{\Omega}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial u_{\infty}^{2}}{\partial x_{j}^{2}}\varphi$ only.

For the purposes of the problem we were working on, it makes sense to get this part only; however, my question is what happened to the  $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u_{\infty}}{\partial x_{j}}\varphi$ part?  Is it somehow $=0$?

I am extremely confused by this, and would very much value someone else's insight! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I suppose $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ denotes the (smooth) functions with compact support contained in $\Omega$? In integration by parts, you usually get a boundary term, $$\int_\Omega f\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j} = \int_{\partial \Omega} fg - \int_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}g.$$ The boundary term vanishes here, since the integrand vanishes on the boundary.

Comment: Is the boundary term what the $uv$ is?

Comment: Yup. In the one-dimensional case, the boundary of the interval consists of two points, one with multiplicity $1$, the other with multiplicity $-1$, and the boundary integral is the sum of the values at these points times the multiplicity, $u(b)v(b) - u(a)v(a)$. In higher dimensions, the boundary is a hypersurface, and the boundary term is more obviously an integral.

Comment: Thank you! I understand EVERYTHING now - you are too awesome! :)